# How can I convert a JSON to another

Tags: javascript, php, json, typescript

I'm receiving a JSON from a Laravel API in this way:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":48,
      "parentid":0,
      "title":"Item 1",
      "child_content":[  
         {  
            "id":49,
            "parentid":48,
            "title":"Itema 1.1",
         },
         {  
            "id":52,
            "parentid":48,
            "title":"Item 1.2",
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":58,
      "parentid":0,
      "title":"Item 2",
      "child_content":[  
         {  
            "id":59,
            "parentid":58,
            "title":"Itema 2.1",
         },
         {  
            "id":60,
            "parentid":58,
            "title":"Item 2.2",
         }
      ]
   } 
]
```

and what I need is change the JSON into this:

```
{
    "data":
    [
        {
            "data":
            {
                "id":68,
                "parentid":0,
                "title":"Item 1"
            },
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "data":
                    {
                        "id":69,
                        "parentid":68,
                        "title":"Item 1.1"
                    },
                },
                {
                    "data":
                    {
                        "id":69,
                        "parentid":68,
                        "title":"Item 1.2"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've been dealing with this... but I'm not able to find the way to do this properly...

How can I do this in PHP or Javascript / TypeScript (Angular 2).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll probably want to construct a tree in memory and then JSONify it.

Comment: where do you get the different `id` from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should achieve your goal. Basically I'm just grabbing `child_content`, renaming it to `children` and copying the 3 other attributes. The `children.map` iteration is putting the existing data inside an object with a key of `data`:

```js
const input = [{"id":48,"parentid":0,"title":"Item 1","child_content":[{"id":49,"parentid":48,"title":"Itema 1.1"},{"id":52,"parentid":48,"title":"Item 1.2"}]},{"id":58,"parentid":0,"title":"Item 2","child_content":[{"id":59,"parentid":58,"title":"Itema 2.1"},{"id":60,"parentid":58,"title":"Item 2.2"}]}]

const output = {
   data: input.map((data) => {
      const { 
        child_content: children,
        id,
        parentId,
        title,
      } = data;

      return {
         id,
         parentId,
         title,
         children: children.map(data => ({data})),
      };
   })
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: your children have no data property.

Comment: you have still the problem with more levels, as nearly all answers.

Comment: @NinaScholz the desired output OP posted has `children` as an array of objects with a `data` key containing the child data, which my answer produces. I think your solution is producing children as an object with a `data` key that is an array: ` { children: { data: [ { ...childData }] }`, which AFAICT is not what OP wanted.

Comment: you was right with the children, but you still have a fixed structure for two levels.

Comment: @NinaScholz I see what you mean now, your solution will convert any level of depth of parent/children nodes (which is great). I did not see OP mention that they would need to support variability in the API responses so I went for a simple approach. Definitely they should use your approach if they need to handle varying levels of depth

Comment: Note: this modifies `data` which may have unexpected consequences elsewhere, and only works once. `map` should not modify the data which it is working with.

Comment: @iblamefish it no longer uses `delete` for removing child_content. so your Note is no longer applicable.

Comment: @RobM. thank you so much for your help. In a comment below I use you approach to reach my goal (deleting child_content which btw is coming now as children). Thank yo all for your help.

Comment: Great, glad to help out @J0sh :-)

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming that the differences in the two datasets are due to copy/paste from different datasets*, you can use the array `map` method to transform the data for you.

`map` works by iterating through each item of an array, and allows you to return a new item in the shape which you'd like.

```js
var input = [{"id":48,"parentid":0,"title":"Item 1","child_content":[{"id":49,"parentid":48,"title":"Itema 1.1"},{"id":52,"parentid":48,"title":"Item 1.2"}]},{"id":58,"parentid":0,"title":"Item 2","child_content":[{"id":59,"parentid":58,"title":"Itema 2.1"},{"id":60,"parentid":58,"title":"Item 2.2"}]}];

var output = {
  data: input.map(function(parent) {
    // return a new object which contains the properties which you need
    return {
      data: {
        id: parent.id,
        parentid: parent.parentid,
        title: parent.title
      },
      // children is an array, so we can use map again to transform them
      children: parent.child_content.map(function(child) {
        return {
          data: {
            id: child.id,
            parentid: parent.id,
            title: child.title
          }
        };
      })
    }
  })
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the structure without mutating the original object with iterating and recursive calls of the `convert` function.

It works for any depth.

```js
function convert(o) {
    var temp = { data: {} };
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        if (k === 'child_content') {
            temp.children = o[k].map(convert);
        } else {
            temp.data[k] = o[k];
        }
    });
    return temp;
}

var data = [{ id: 48, parentid: 0, title: "Item 1", child_content: [{ id: 49, parentid: 48, title: "Itema 1.1" }, { id: 52, parentid: 48, title: "Item 1.2" }] }, { id: 58, parentid: 0, title: "Item 2", child_content: [{ id: 59, parentid: 58, title: "Itema 2.1" }, { id: 60, parentid: 58, title: "Item 2.2" }] }],
    result = { data: data.map(convert) };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much all of you guys, you're amazing; I'm testing the solutions, and apparently all of them works, but like Nina said, maybe with depth supporting is better.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I thought "guys" was for all genders :P

My English sucks :D

Comment: Nina, how can I do to return an array of objects instead of objects like Rob says... because your solution can be used with different depth levels, which is really important. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @J0sh, i don't get you. maybe an example would help.

Comment: This is an example of what is returning each function, Rob one and yours:

Rob M.:  `[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]`

Nina Scholz:  `Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 6: Object}`

And what I need is your depth functionality in Rob's format

Comment: i see no difference between the output of rob's and my answer.

Comment: Mmm, Rob is returning an Array of objects, and you are returning an object with nested objects.

Comment: the result is identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var json = [{"id": 48,"parentid": 0,"title": "Item 1","child_content": [{"id": 49,"parentid": 48,"title": "Itema 1.1",}, {"id": 52,"parentid": 48,"title": "Item 1.2",}]}, {"id": 58,"parentid": 0,"title": "Item 2","child_content": [{"id": 59,"parentid": 58,"title": "Itema 2.1",}, {"id": 60,"parentid": 58,"title": "Item 2.2",}]}],
    result = {
      data: json.map(function (item) {
        return {
          data: {
            id: item.id,
            parentid: item.parentid,
            title: item.title
          },
          children: item.child_content.map(function (childItem) {
            return {
              data: {
                id: childItem.id,
                parentid: childItem.parentid,
                title: childItem.title
              }
            }
          })
        };
      })
    };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I finally did is maybe not too much elegant... but it works, probably I should create a recursive function to manage different nested levels. I took the @RobM solution and replicated the children functionality at the second level like this:

```
convert(input)
{
    const output =
    {
       data: input.map((data) =>
       {
          const { children: children } = data;
          delete data.children;
          return {
             data,
             children: children.map(data =>
             {
                const { children: children } = data;
                delete data.children;
                return {
                    data,
                    children: children.map(data => ({data})),
                };
            }),
          };
       })
    }

    return output.data;
}
```